# I face a Python singularity in lists

Tags: python, list, towers-of-hanoi

I coded a Hanoi towers program which print each step of the game

```
#Hanoi Towers game

n = 3 # number of disks
beg = [ n-i for i in range(n)]
mid = []
end = []
towers = [beg, mid, end]

def move(beg, end) :
summit_beg = 0
summit_end = 0
if len(towers[beg]) > 0 :
summit_beg = towers[beg][len(towers[beg]) - 1]

    if summit_beg > summit_end and summit_end != 0 :
        print("err: summit", beg, ">summit", end, "Gameover")
    else:
        towers[beg].pop(len(towers[beg]) - 1)
        towers[end].append(summit_beg)
        print(towers) ; print()

def hanoi(n, beg = 0, mid = 1, end = 2):
if n > 0 :
hanoi(n - 1, beg, end, mid)
move(beg, end)
hanoi(n - 1, mid, beg, end)
hanoi(n)

out :
[[3, 2], [], [1]]

[[3], [2], [1]]

[[3], [2, 1], []]

[[], [2, 1], [3]]

[[1], [2], [3]]

[[1], [], [3, 2]]

[[], [], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Now, for a reinforcement learning project, I need to create a states-space list of that each steps of the game, which so is a list to fill in as my learning agent go encounting each states of the game (so lists of the Hanoi disks 3, 2, 1).

So I want finally to output a list like this :

```
Space = [ [[3, 2], [], [1]] ,

[[3], [2], [1]] ,

[[3], [2, 1], []] ,

[[], [2, 1], [3]] ,

[[1], [2], [3]] ,

[[1], [], [3, 2]] ,

[[], [], [3, 2, 1]] ]
```

Let's observe a test code

```
space = []
temp = [[] for i in range(4)]
j = -1

print(j)
temp[j] = []
print(temp[j])
space.append(temp[j])
print(space) ; print()
j += 1

print(j)
temp[j] = [0]
print(temp[j])
space.append(temp[j])
print(space) ; print()
j += 1

print(j)
temp[j] = [1]
print(temp[j])
space.append(temp[j])
print(space) ; print()
j += 1

print(j)
temp[j] = [2]
print(temp[j])
space.append(temp[j])
print(space)

out :
-1
[]
[[]]

0
[0]
[[], [0]]

1
[1]
[[], [0], [1]]

2
[2]
[[], [0], [1], [2]]
```

When you examine this code you observe that the "space" list fills up as the counter j increases, and this with lists that are different from each other.

However if I inject the same process in the following program (so in the previous Hanoi towers code):

```
#Towers of Hanoi

n = 3
Beg = [ n - i for i in range(n)]
Mid = []
End = []

Towers = [ Beg, Mid, End]

Space = [ [[ n - i for i in range(n)], [], []] ]
Temp = [ [] for i in range(n**3)]
j = 0
def move(Beg, End):
summit_B = 0
summit_E = 0
if len(Towers[Beg]) > 0 :
summit_B = Towers[Beg][len(Towers[Beg]) - 1]

    if len(Towers[End]) > 0 :
        summit_E = Towers[End][len(Towers[End]) - 1]
        
    if summit_B > summit_E and summit_E != 0 :
        print("Error")
    else :
        global j # global not forgotten
        Towers[Beg].pop(len(Towers[Beg]) - 1)
        Towers[End].append(summit_B)
        print(Towers) ; print() # The list Towers change at each step
        
        print(j) ; print() # counter increase
        Temp[j] = Towers
        print(Temp[j]) ; print() ; print() # We check that we place Towers
         # (each time a different list) to a variable also incremented
         # different each time
        
        Space.append(Temp[j]) # The list is therefore supposed to be filled as
         # measurement with each different turns (like in the test code)
    
        print(Space) ; print() ; print() ; print()
        # BUT we end up with (j - 1) times the same Towers list at each increment (corresponding the list in the step of the game)
    
        j += 1

def hanoi(n, Beg = 0, Mid = 1, End = 2):
if n > 0 :
hanoi(n - 1, Beg, End, Mid)
move(Beg, End)
hanoi(n - 1, Mid, Beg, End)
hanoi(n)

Out :

[[3, 2], [], [1]] # first game step (list Towers)
0                 # verification of the counter j
[[3, 2], [], [1]] # verification of the variable Temp[j] logically increased, which contains the Towers

# Space :

[[[3, 2, 1], [], []], [[3, 2], [], [1]]] # so far so good with .append( Temp[0])

[[3], [2], [1]] # next state of the towers of Hanoi game
1               # same thing : counter verified

[[3], [2], [1]] # Same thing: the NEW variable Temp[j = 1] contains the new step-state of the game (the list Towers is refreshed), it's supposed to be verified.

# print(Space.append(Temp[1] = Towers) ):

[[[3, 2, 1], [], []], [[3], [2], [1]], [[3], [2], [1]]] # ?? 2 times the #same Towers list at step 3... ?

# not expected ..

# For me, we was supposed to obtain :

# "[[[3, 2, 1], [], []], [[3, 2], [], [1]], [[3], [2], [1]]]"

... then same problem

... then same problem
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

The code in question is badly formatted and it does not really work as is. However, the problem you face is related to the fact that you insert the reference to the list in question, not the copy.

If you change the

```
Space.append(Temp[j])
```

to

```
Space.append(Temp[j][:])
```

the it will copy the contents when appending so it won't be affected by further changes.

Comment: I obtain the same thing